# IOS: How to use a UIAlertView inside of a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I've been working on this problem for some time now and can't find a solution that works. I'm creating a game where each player is assigned a random name. At the end of the game, if one or more players have scores that qualify them for the all time leaderboard, I want to loop through all the players, display a UIAlertView where they can enter their real name, and then save that name back into my player object. However, I can't get the loop to stop, show the alert view, wait for a response, and then continue. Can anybody help me out?

Heres my loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [leaderboard count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *player = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[leaderboard objectAtIndex:i]];
    if ([[player valueForKey:@"isCurrentPlayer"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]){
        // getRealPlayerName takes in a name parameter and displays an alertview
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getRealPlayerName:) withObject:[player valueForKey:@"playerName"] waitUntilDone:YES];
        // nameFromAlertView is a local variable that is set when the user enters a name in the alertview.
        [player setValue:[self nameFromAlertView] forKey:@"playerName"];
        [player setValue:@"" forKey:@"isCurrentPlayer"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that several players will use one device?

Comment: @vikingosegundo, Yes, players will be using the same devices.

Comment: You _can_ do it in a loop (by leveraging a semaphore and a background queue), only you don't want to, believe me. You are trying to fight the framework, let it help you instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do it in a loop.

instead save the users and the points in an array, call the method, that displays the UIAlertView. get the first users infos from the array and remove those infos from the array. set the delegate for the alert view. once, the first info is entered, the delegate methods of the UIAlertView are called (`alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`). there u handle the entered information, than check, if there is still something in the array, and if so, call the first method again

---

```
-(void)promptForInput
{
    self.currentUserInfo = userArray[0]; //userarray is mutable, self.currentUserInfo is a property for the current user
    [userArray removeObject:self.currentUserInfo];
    //configure UIAlertView
    alertView.delegate = self;

}


//once the user hit a altertview button, this delegate method gets called
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
     //save/process entered data, self.currentUserInfo hold the current user.

    if([userArray count]> 0){
        [self promptForInput];
    }
}
```

---

if you are familiar with blocks, you could also use a third party code, that allows the usage of blocks instead of delegation. But in the blocks you would do basically the same: call another block as-long users in the array are unprocessed.

One of those additions: [Mugunth Kumar — Block Based UIAlertView and UIActionSheet](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-block-based-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet/)

Comment: +1 for the code (I think we had roughly the same idea). I would remove the object in the delegate function, so that you know the current user for which the delegate is called, but that is just a minor matter of taste.

Comment: This is the basic logic that I used and it worked great. Obviously I had to make a few tweeks that allowed me to save the data entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

The alert view is only displayed and the events processed when the program control returns to the main runloop. Therefore waiting in

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getRealPlayerName:) withObject:[player valueForKey:@"playerName"] waitUntilDone:YES];
```

blocks the alert view from being displayed at all.

What you can do is:

- Start an alert view for the first player.
- In the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate function, record the data and start a new alert view for the next player (if that was not the last player).

You would have to store the current player index in a property of your class. Alternatively, you can assign the current index to `myAlertView.tag`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm confused about how I would got about starting an alertview for each player, without using a loop.

Comment: @Weston: You cannot do it in a loop. You start the alert view for the first player. When that is finished (`didDismissWithButtonIndex` is called) you start the alert view for the next player.